# How to provide multiple working directories to run CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: terraform, github-actions, azure-policy

I'm trying to run below YAML file with a job. How can I specify working directory, if I want this to trigger when there is change in any child folders?

For example: below is the snippet of my working directory structure and I want CI to trigger when I make changes to any child folders under Policy folder.

[image]

Any changes in Initiative and Definitions should trigger the event.
What should be the working directory path?

```
name: 'deployment of azure policies'
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    paths:
        - "Policy/Initiatives/*"

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
      env:
       TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
       TF_INPUT: false
       **TF_WORKING_DIR: Policy/Initiatives/**
       ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
       ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
       ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
       ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
     # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
        - name: Checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

I tried below, but didn't work:

```
TF_Working_DIR: "Policy/"
```

It says no configuration files found (it's correct as the configuration files are in the child folders).

However, when I mention Policy/Initiatives or Policy/Definitions, the work is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

***I created one Github repository with below folders:-***

[image]

**I agree to the answer by @Philip and @jessehouwing**

In order to trigger the github actions from child folder you can use `"Policy-Assignment/**/*"`  and add the below code in your Github workflow:-

> ```yaml
>  name: 'deployment of azure policies' on:   push:
>     branches: [ "main" ]   pull_request:
>     paths:
>         - "Policy-Assignment/**/*"
>
> jobs:   build-and-deploy:
>       env:
>        TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
>        TF_INPUT: false
>        TF_WORKING_DIR: Policy/Policy-Assignment/**/
>        ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
>        ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
>        ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
>        ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
>       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>       steps:
>      # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
>         - name: Checkout
>           uses: actions/checkout@v3
> ```

[image]

**Output:-**

The workflow ran successfully like below:-

[image]

**UPDATED:-**

You can specify the full path to your folder in your code like below:-

```yaml
name: 'deployment of azure policies'
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    paths:
        - "Policy-Assignment/**/*"

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
      env:
       TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
       TF_INPUT: false
       TF_WORKING_DIR: Policy/Policy-Assignment/Initiatives <add your complete path to Policy-Assignmeent folder as my Policy-Assignment folder is inside Policy folder, I have added path like above>
       ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
       ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
       ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
       ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
     # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
        - name: Checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v3
        - name: Terraform Init
          run: terraform init
        - name: Terraform Format
          run: terraform fmt -check
        - name: Terraform Validate
          run: terraform validate -no-color
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Alternatively, **You can make use of `find` method in your code to find the files from child folders like below:-**

```yaml
name: 'deployment of azure policies'
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    paths:
        - "Policy-Assignment/**/*"

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
      env:
       TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
       TF_INPUT: false
       ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
       ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
       ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
       ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
     # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
        - name: Checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v3
        - name: Find configuration files
          run: |
            find Policy-Assignment -name "*.tf"
            find Policy-Assignment -name "*.json"
          id: find_files
        - name: Deploy policies
          run: |
            terraform init
            terraform validate
            terraform plan -var-file=variables.tfvars -out=tfplan -input=false -no-color
            terraform apply -input=false -auto-approve tfplan
          if: steps.find_files.outputs.stdout != ''
```

**Output:-**

***Initiative i1.json from Initiatives child folder and a.json Policy definition was found and code ran successfully like below:-***

[image]

Comment: @jessehouwing Sorry I missed that it was an Github action workflow, Can you check my updated answer?

Comment: It still didnt work...I get the same error:

Run terraform init
/home/runner/work/_temp/121684ad-5477-4f35-a0eb-9d5aaad18cfe/terraform-bin init
Terraform initialized in an empty directory!

The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.

Comment: @PrashanthP Try to add the full path of the child folder like here  paths:
        - "Policy-Assignment/Definitions/*"

Comment: This is the entire code:

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
      env:
       TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
       TF_INPUT: false
       TF_WORKING_DIR: Policy-Assignment/**/*
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
           

        - name: Terraform Init
          run: terraform init
          

        - name: Terraform Format
          run: terraform fmt -check
    
    
        - name: Terraform Validate
          run: terraform validate -no-color

Comment: @PrashanthP I have updated the answer with new steps. Check the Updated section of the answer and the Alternative that I added in the updated answer. I was able to fetch the correct child directory in both my Updated codes. Try find method as mentioned in the answer and cheeck?

Comment: Hi SiddeshDesai, thank you for the code. I'm able to fetch the details. However, Deploy stuff is not working

Comment: @Prashanth PDo you have necessary permissions to deploy Azure policies on Portal? Also any specific errors?

Comment: No Errors, but it is skipping Deploy Policies Job.
Also, I dont see you providing terraform working directory

Comment: Remove this line -  if: steps.find_files.outputs.stdout != '' and try to run the workflow again looks like the if statement is not evaluating to true

Comment: Also, Try running this command -- name: Output find_files result
  run: echo "${{ steps.find_files.outputs.stdout }}" and check what it outputs in the console?

Comment: I tried removing the code...now its back to square one....Terraform initialized in a empty folder....As suggested by you in the first way, it was working earlier too....However, I have child folders and when I make changes to any child folder....I must come back and update the .yml file with TF_Working_Dir.
I'm looking for an alternative (something similar to the PATH,  Policy/**/*)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working "**Github**" example of a pipeline deploying policies under the "Policies" folder:

```
name: 'deployment of azure policies' 

env:
  TF_WORKING_DIR: "Policy/Definitions/" 
  ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
  ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
  ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches: [ "main" ]
    paths: 
    - "Policy/Definitions"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Display GitHub Context
      id: context
      run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
    
    - name: Output Working Dir
      id: outputworkingdir
      run: find . -printf '%y %p\n'

    - name: 'Az CLI login'
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
    
    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
    
    - name: Terraform Init
      working-directory: ${{ env.TF_WORKING_DIR }}
      id: init
      run: terraform init

    - name: Terraform Plan
      id: plan
      working-directory: ${{ env.TF_WORKING_DIR }}
      run: terraform plan -no-color 2>&1 | tee /tmp/terraform.plan
      continue-on-error: true
```

You can find the example over [HERE](https://github.com/pvyver/TFdeploy).

Comment: Because the example in the question shows a Github action,  not an Azure pipeline.

Comment: Thank you @jessehowwing. However, I want initiatives and single policy in different folders and stuck at providing the working directory for Terraform init. 
Is there a way to provide terraform working directory as multiple child directories?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `/**` to denote a recursive include.

```
name: 'deployment of azure policies'
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - "Policy-Assignments/Initiatives/**"
```

See:

- [Workflow Syntax - on.<push|pull_request|pull_request_target>.<paths|paths-ignore>](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore)

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I need something similar to this for tf_working_dir....Can I mention multiple working directors for Terraform Init, as I have multiple child folders...one for single policy and another one for initiatives

Comment: Not sure what you want here... I suspect , if you have multiple terraform plans, you'll need to add multiple calls to the terraform action. If you want to only deploy the changed plans, you'll need to create multiple workflows.